# SEOmatic & Tags Manager plugin

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I'm trying to get SEOmatic meta title & meta description overrides on a tag page that is managed via the [Tags plugin by ethercreative](https://github.com/ethercreative/tags/). I'm using the automatic render feature of SEOmatic, and have the appropriate SEO fields on the tags pages in the CP, with overrides in place. Although on the pages via the front-end, the overrides are not being included. Is there a way to get these two plugins to work together?

The site is on Craft 3.8.6 with SEOmatic 3.4.52 and Tags 1.0.9

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be some misunderstanding here... the Tags plugin just lets you manage Craft CMS Tags:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/tags.html

Tags are just elements that you can use to add taxonomy information, they don't have their own separate URLs/pages... so adding SEOmatic fields to the Tag field layouts isn't going to do anything.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for popping in here, @andrew.welch. I have a template set up to display entries that are tagged with any given tag, and I'm trying to add the SEOmatic-managed title & description overrides to those templates/pages. Do I need to capture the input from the SEO fields on that template and register them so the automatic render feature is aware? If so, can you point me to some documentation on how to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: Digging deeper into the SEOmatic docs i've been able to solve the issue. I used the {% do seomatic.meta.seoTitle() %} function on my tag templates and pulled in the overrides on those tag entries. All sorted now, thanks again.